# Can't change an Array in a Loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm starting programming with C language making some easy programs but I am having trouble with a specific code. The program should make an Array of 3 elements, get an input from user and depending of the input change some array elements. But I don't know why the code jumps the first `for` loop.
Here's a piece of the code :

```
int lock[3] = {3, 3, 3}, moves; 
char move;

while (1) 
{
    scanf("%c", &move);

    if (move == 'r' || move == 'R') 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i == 2; i++) 
        {
            lock[i]++;
            if (lock[i] == 4) lock[i] = lock[i] % 3;
        }

        printf("Lock :");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (j == 2) printf(" %d.\n", lock[2]);
            else printf(" %d,", lock[j]);
        }

        moves++;
    }
}
```

The output of it is

```
Lock : 3, 3, 3.
```

But it should return

```
Lock : 3, 1, 1.
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop never executes:

```
for (int i = 1; i == 2; i++)
```

The value of `i` begins at `1`, but the condition for loop continuation is `i == 2`, which evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

== is your equality operator so it checks if i is equal to 2 at the starting of the loop. But when you write

```
   for(i=1;i==2;i++)
```

i is initialized to 1 and so i==2 is false . Thus the loop never executes.Try this code:

```
   for(i=1;i<3;i++)
```

It checks if i is less than 3 so when i=1 and i=2 the loop excecutes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your for loop to be executable you should change

the test condition `i==2`  to either `i<=2` or `i<3`. Your problem will be solved.

`i==2` will evaluate to  false as value of i is initialized with 1

Answer (score 0):

In your first `for` loop, the condition `i==2` evaluates to false since the value of `i` is 1. Hence the first `for` loop is skipped.

You should change it to `for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)` or `for(int i=1; i<2; i++)` as per your requirements.